# I want to move from one form to another in same html page ,like a question answer quiz page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to iterate my code in js through the list of options:

option=["1","2","3"]

3 forms to appear: first with the value 1 then when I submit it then next form should appear with value:2

Comment: And what is your question about that? What have you tried so far and what is the problem you are facing? You need to show a [mcve] of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use innerHTML property on a div which contains the form you want to update.
Whenever the submit button is pressed for a question, call a function to increase the counter. Depending on the counter take what you want to place in the div. Eg.

```
function updateForm() {
    let element = document.querySelector('.question');
    let htmlToAdd = '<form> ... </form>'
    element.innerHTML = htmlToAdd;
}
```

A better approach would be to use an array of objects with each object containing information about what is to be added to the HTML.